# Wayland/Weston freezes

Tags: raspbian, terminal, wayland, weston

I have freshly installed last Raspbian and updated it. When computer boots up to console, I log in and start command weston-launch. The output of command is something about initializing Raspberry Pi's backend - something like that - but when I want to type something into console it's just frozen and there is not any GUI.

What can I do and how to solve this problem?

Comment: Has this been solved? If so, please mark the answer that fixed it as such. We're trying to get this site up to par and the Q:A ratio is really bad. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The build documentation for Wayland on Raspberry Pi indicates that it requires a recent firmware version, and a too old version may cause rpi-backend to malfunction. They suggest using rpi-update to update the firmware.

Also - the final 1.2 version of Wayland/Weston was released around mid-July, and is the version that integrates the RaspberryPi backend, so bugs that may have been in earlier releases could also be causing issues - it may be worth updating and trying again (given that it is now 3-4 weeks since the original question posting).

(Source http://wayland.freedesktop.org/raspberrypi.html and http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/wayland-devel/2013-July/010278.html)

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is quite old, but I couldn't find any helpful answers of today.
I ran into the same trouble as the original poster, weston-lauch just freezes after the line "Initializing Raspberry Pi's backend".

I did a firmware upgrade (rpi-update), edited /boot/config.txt as suggested in http://wayland.freedesktop.org/raspberrypi.html, but it still kept freezing for me.

What entirely solved the problem was to run weston-launch with sudo!! No freezing, the GUI started.

Note that I always log in via a different account (not the standard "pi"-user), and maybe some missing permission for my user crash the weston when run without sudo. I still doubt that this is intended behavior...

Answer (score 0):

It's hanging because the user you're running weston as doesn't have the necessary permissions.

You need to add whichever user you're running `weston-launch` as to the groups `video` and `input`, and edit a config file.

First add a new udev rule, then add your user to both `video` and `input` (run as root. run `sudo -i` to enter a root console. Press Ctrl+D to exit):

```
echo 'SUBSYSTEM=="vchiq",GROUP="video",MODE="0660"' > /etc/udev/rules.d/10-vchiq-permissions.rules
usermod -a -G video [your_username]

echo 'SUBSYSTEM=="input", GROUP="input", MODE="0660"' > /etc/udev/rules.d/99-input.rules
echo 'KERNEL=="tty[0-9]*", GROUP="tty", MODE="0660"' >> /etc/udev/rules.d/99-input.rules
usermod -a -G input [your_username]
```